# Matplotlib.patches.Wedge animation not working

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, wedge

I have just started animating my matplotlib patches. In my current work, I want to display a visualization where there exist a wedge that change it size through time. However, I am getting a static wedge, for a reason beyond my vision.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.patches

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
plt.grid(True)
# patch_one = matplotlib.patches.Circle((0, 0), 1)
patch_one = matplotlib.patches.Wedge((0,0), 1, -10, 10)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    patch_one.radius = 1
    ax.add_patch(patch_one)
    return patch_one,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    patch_one.radius +=i*0.0001
    return patch_one,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

I tried the code by replacing patch_one by a circular patch and it did work (left that part commented out in the code).

Comment: Thank you for the clear self-sufficient code to test! However, be careful when copying and pasting. The code is now intestable without fixing a small bug. (On line 12: `patch_one = ...`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems to need two small changes:

```
# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    patch_one.r +=i*0.0001
    patch_one._recompute_path()
    return patch_one,
```

Why:

1. the attribute `r` defines the radius, there is no attribute `radius`. On the other hand, you may (and probably should) use the method `set_radius()`.
2. For some reason or another, the internal method `_recompute_path` needs to be called manually to recompute the actual path.

The latter one seems like an omission in the source, the method `set_radius` could call `_recompute_path`. However, there are wiser people (at least @tcaswell) who may be able to tell if this is a bug or if there is something else going on.

(By the way, are you sure you want to say `patch_one.r += i*0.0001`? The animation looks a bit odd with that. Maybe you mean `patch_one.r = 1 + i*.0001`?)

Comment: You are right Wedge doesn't have radius. I have been working on theta1 and theta2 to create a rotating Wedge which I replaced by radius in order to use the same code as a circle. I have tried to apply your suggestion but I don't have both set_radius() and _recompute_path methods. 
I am using `matplotlib.__version__ = '1.1.1rc'
`

Comment: Get a newer version! (Sorry, I do not see any other reasonable solution.)

Comment: So all I needed to do was `sudo pip install matplotlib[all] --upgrade` Thanks @DrV